Missing observations (incomplete data) in Linear Mixed Model
I am running LMM for longitudinal analysis using data with only 2 observations (baseline + one follow-up) per participant. If some participants only have baseline outcomes, will LMM automatically exclude them? Or are they still included in the model?
I checked the number of observations and number of groups, it seems like the IDs with incomplete observations (only baseline) were excluded. But why? I thought LMM could handle imbalanced data?

The set-up is not entirely clear to me. Do you have an outcome variable measured at two occasions (baseline and follow-up), or do you want to use the follow-up as an outcome, and the baseline measure as predictor? In case of the latter, you might not need a mixed model if your observations are not clustered within groups, because you don't have multiple outcome measures per person. In this case, if observations have missing values on the follow-up measure, you cannot include these observations in your regression model without treating these missing values, because you cannot calculate the likelihood for these observations.
If you use both baseline and follow-up measures as outcome and have a different set of (possibly time-varying) predictors, then you do need a mixed model, you could fit the model without treating the missing values. However, then you reduce the number of observations for these persons, because they will only have a single measurement. Then, for these persons, there is no second measurement occasion. It might still be worthwhile to consider some appropriate treatment of these missing values (such as estimating the model using full information maximum likelihood, or using multiple imputation to impute the missing values).

This is correct except for the idea that observations from people with only a single measurement drop out of the model completely. They don't directly help estimate the difference between baseline and follow-up, of course, but they do improve the estimate of the population mean baseline and the among-subject variation at the baseline ...

Yes, sorry for my ambiguous phrasing. With "these observations" I meant these measurement occasions (or these rows, assuming the data is stored in long-format, with every row a measurement occasion for a person). Thanks for the remark, I adjusted the text accordingly.

Thank you so much for your answers! Yes I do use both baseline and follow-up as the outcomes, and I have time-varying exposure. It's good to know that those with only one observation do help improve the baseline estimates.
